# Can I give dynamic paths for images and css purely in client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I give dynamic paths for images and css through jquery/javascript/html or any other technology available in client side? Below is my **dummy** code:

```
<html>
  my_constant_path = "/yes/I/got/this/"
 <head> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<my_constant_path>" + "style.css"/> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>
   <img src= "<my_constant_path>" + "abc.png"/> 
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I cannot use server side script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are going to apply the `my_constant_path` to all the images/links**

You could use `<base>` element at the head section and change its `href` attribute via JavaScript as follows:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <base href="">
  <script>
    function setBaseURL(url) { 
      document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0].href = url;
    } 

    setBaseURL("http://placehold.it/");
  </script>
</head>
```

Then enter all the `href`/`src` attributes of the elements relatively:

```html
<img src="200x150" alt="">
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sonoh/1/edit)**.

Comment: That's an interesting method. OP should be aware this changes the path for ALL elements on the page, not only certain elements.

Comment: But will this work setBaseURL("/yes/I/got/this/") or I must provide a url path starting http://?

Comment: @user2645830 It will work as the leading `/` points to the root of the domain. No need to use the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

For "purely client side", using JavaScript is the only way.

```
<head>
  <link id="stylesheet1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
  <script>
    var my_constant_path = "assets/";
    $(function(){
      $("#stylesheet1").attr("href", my_constant_path + "style.css");
      $("#image1").attr("src", my_constant_path + "abc.png");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="image1"/> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard front-end scripting language is JavaScript. To embed it directly in HTML, you would need to write the script inside `<script>` elements. For you `my_constant_path` declaration:

```
<script>
  var my_constant_path = "/yes/I/got/this/";
</script>
```

You can execute script and write to the document during the document's execution using `document.write()`, but you can't insert script elements (or any other kind of element) inside tags, so it's not possible to dynamically insert `my_constant_path` inside the `href` and `src` attributes: instead you need to either write the entire tags:

```
<head>
  <script>
    document.write( '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + my_constant_path + '"style.css"/>' );
  </script>
</head>
```

…or wait til the tags have been rendered and then change their attributes afterwards:

```
<head>
  <link id="dynamicLink" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script>
    document.getElementById( 'dynamicLink' ).setAttribute( 'href', my_constant_path + 'style.css' );
  </script>
</head>
```